# Finding communities in a highly connected network using NetworkX and Gephi

Tags: python, pandas, networkx, gephi

I am attempting to look at communities in handles followed by a given set of users. I've collected all of the handles followed by the given set of users and trimmed them down to the most relevant ones (i.e. removed those with only a small number of followers in the set that are essentially noise). In this case the number of given users is 69 and the number of handles I'm trying to cluster is 435.

I'm using NetworkX to build a graph of this network. Each followed handle constitutes a node and all pairwise combinations of handles followed by a given user are undirected edges. For example, given user1 follows handle 1, handle2, and handle3: handle1, handle2, and handle3 are nodes and handle1-handle2, handle1-handle3, handle2-handle3 are edges. I end up with 435 nodes and 81,182 edges.

I then export this graph to Gephi for analysis, but it appears to be too interconnected to extract anything interesting. Finding the graph's modularity only gives two massive and mostly unhelpful communities. I've tried various methods of weighting the edges and nodes, but can't seem to get anything meaningful. Perhaps I need to determine some of these edges as irrelevant, but I'm not sure how. When I look at each node's edges the ones with the highest weight are in fact the most closely related handles, but this doesn't come through in the modularity analysis.

My code is below, can anyone provide any guidance for how I might find the communities here?

```
# build a network of followedUsers
followedUsersGraph = nx.Graph()

# followedUsersSorted is a Pandas series of handles followed with userid
# as the id and the number of users from the set following as the value
for i, user in enumerate(followedUsersSorted.iteritems()):
    followedUsersGraph.add_node(i)
    followedUsersGraph.node[i]['user'] = str(user[0])
    followedUsersGraph.node[i]['weight'] = int(user[1])

# followedUsersMatrix is a Pandas DataFrame acting as a binary matrix
# with rows of given users and columns of followed handles
# convert the column labels to node ids
followedUsersMatrix.columns = range(len(followedUsersMatrix.columns))

# convert the matrix into tuple of edge tuples w/ weight
edgeTuples = []
for _, vector in followedUsersMatrix.iterrows():
    # each user from the set can only provide a total weight of 1
    # the more handles they follow the less weight they contribute to the edge
    edges = [t for t in combinations(vector[vector != 0].index, 2)]
    weight = 1.0/len(edges)
    edgeTuples.extend([(edge, weight) for edge in edges])

# add the edges to the graph incrementing the weight for repeated edges
for edge, weight in edgeTuples:
    if followedUsersGraph.has_edge(*edge):
        followedUsersGraph[edge[0]][edge[1]]['weight'] += weight
    else:
        followedUsersGraph.add_edge(*edge, weight = weight)

nx.write_gexf(followedUsersGraph, 'fug.gexf')
```

Comment: You have to bear in mind that it is _scale-free_ graphs that exhibit modularity. Since your graph is close to complete, you have to find another way of approaching the problem. Would it be an idea to discard unpopular edges and to keep only a small fraction of total edges?

Comment: Do you have any recommendation on how I might determine which edges are significant?

Comment: You alreeady have weight, so this is something for a start, alternatively you can use [Edge betweeness centrality](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.edge_betweenness_centrality.html)